# Select an interval of values that is equal or greater than the previous value

Tags: sql

My problem is that I don't get the first value in the interval.

The values in the increasing interval in table 1 is Id1-Id3, Id4-Id5, Id9-Id13 and Id14-Id15, but
the result i Table 2 is Id2-Id3, Id5,Id10-Id13 and Id 15 missing Id1, Id4, Id9 and Id14.

I just can't figure out how to get the first value included in the query.

PSS Table containing the datasource:

```
ID  Date    Value

1   2012-04-20 0,166666666666667
2   2012-04-25 0,2
3   2012-04-28 0,235294117647059
4   2012-05-05 0,111111111111111
5   2012-05-07 0,416666666666667
6   2012-05-08 0,25
7   2012-05-09 0,166666666666667
8   2012-05-10 0,142857142857143
9   2012-05-11 0,125
10  2012-05-12 0,375
11  2012-05-13 0,5
12  2012-05-14 0,625
13  2012-05-15 0,75
14  2012-05-16 0,625
15  2012-05-17 0,75
```

And this query:

```
SELECT Id, Date, Value
FROM PSS p
WHERE p.Value >=
(SELECT Value
FROM PSS
WHERE Id = p.Id-1)
```

Resulting in tabel 2:

```
Id  Date    Value

2   2012-04-25 0,2
3   2012-04-28 0,235294117647059
5   2012-05-07 0,416666666666667
10  2012-05-12 0,375
11  2012-05-13 0,5
12  2012-05-14 0,625
13  2012-05-15 0,75
15  2012-05-17 0,75
```

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: The ids are unique. The dates are also unique. If you want the maximum value per id (or date) you'll still get all the rows. If you want the overall maximum, you'll get only one (distinct) result tuple.

Comment: @ChrisGessler he is looking for a result that contains rows from the PSS Table with "ids" like this : 1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13,14,15

Comment: Great, it works exactly as expected. Thanks to anouar204

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select id, date, value 
from PSS p1
where value >= (select p2.amount from PSS p2 where p2.id=p1.id - 1) 
      or value <= (select p3.amount from PSS p3 where P3.id=p1.id + 1)
```